# How to make iteration in Compute() method over list of class extends RecursiveAction/RecursiveTask

Tags: java, multithreading, fork-join

I tried many ways to get the below scenario works, and the result is infinite printing fork fork fork.. I tried to debug, but it always wait in `task.join();` for long time with no result.  I understand the concept of fork/join well, I can use it when I have task can be divided into sub-parts such as: Fibonacci, and Maximum of arrays. The scenario here is different in sense that I have to an iterate in compute which isn't recursively. Can anyone help ?

### CompositePoolTest

```
 import java.util.Random;
 import java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool;

 public class CompositePoolTest {

Random random = new Random(123);
int done = 0;
int rest= 0;
int tt = 4;
ForkJoinPool pool = new ForkJoinPool(tt);
int M= 1000;
int N = 1000;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new CompositePoolTest().compute();
}

private void compute() {
    double[][] original_matrix = new double[M][N];
    original_matrix = radom_intialization();
    double[][] temp_matrix = new double[M][N];
    done= 0;
    rest= (M * N - done) / (tt- 0);
    DynamicCompositeFinder dynamicFinder = new DynamicCompositeFinder(done,rest,original_matrix,temp_matrix);
    new ForkJoinPool().invoke(dynamicFinder);
}

private double[][] radom_intialization() {
    double [][] grid_matrix = new double[M][N];
    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            grid_matrix[i][j] = random.nextDouble()+0.10;
        }
    return grid_matrix;
}
 }
```

### DynamicCompositeFinder

```
package test;

import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool;
import java.util.concurrent.RecursiveAction;

    public class DynamicCompositeFinder extends RecursiveAction {
int done = 0;
int rest = 0;
int pp = 4;
ForkJoinPool pool = new ForkJoinPool(pp);
// Matrix dimensions
int M = 1000;
int N = 1000;
int x = 0;
int y = 0;
int niteration = 150;
double[][] original_matrix = new double[M][N];
double[][] temp_matrix = new double[M][N];

public DynamicCompositeFinder(int done, int rest, double[][] original_matrix, double[][] temp_matrix) {
    this.done = done;
    this.rest = rest;
    this.original_matrix = original_matrix;
    this.temp_matrix = temp_matrix;

    int limit = done + rest;
    for (int i = done; i < limit; i++) {
        x = i / M;
        y = i % M;
        temp_matrix[x][y] = fun_calculation(x, y, original_matrix);
    }
}

private double fun_calculation(int x2, int y2, double[][] original_matrix2) {
     double temp = 2 * (original_matrix2[x][y] );
    return temp;
}

@Override
protected void compute() {
    for (int i = 0; i < niteration; i++) {
        done = 0;
        List<RecursiveAction> forks = new LinkedList<RecursiveAction>();
        for (int p = 0; p < pp; p++) // n is predefined n = 9
        {
            rest = (M * N - done) / (pp - p);
            DynamicCompositeFinder finder = new DynamicCompositeFinder(done, rest, original_matrix, temp_matrix);
            p++;
            forks.add((RecursiveAction) finder.fork());
            System.out.println("Fork-" + Thread.currentThread().getName()
                    + "  State: " + Thread.currentThread().getState());
        }

        for (RecursiveAction task : forks) {
            task.join();
            System.out.println("Join-" + Thread.currentThread().getName()
                    + "  State: " + Thread.currentThread().getState());
        }
        original_matrix = copy_matrix(temp_matrix);
    }
}

public double[][] copy_matrix(double [][] matrix)
{
    double [][] out= new double [matrix.length][matrix[0].length];
    for(int i=0;i<matrix.length;i++)
    {
        out[i]= matrix[i].clone();
    }
    return out;
}}
```

### Output

```
Fork-ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1  State: RUNNABLE
Fork-ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1  State: RUNNABLE
Fork-ForkJoinPool-1-worker-2  State: RUNNABLE
Fork-ForkJoinPool-1-worker-2  State: RUNNABLE
Fork-ForkJoinPool-1-worker-3  State: RUNNABLE
Fork-ForkJoinPool-1-worker-4  State: RUNNABLE
Fork-ForkJoinPool-1-worker-4  State: RUNNABLE
Fork-ForkJoinPool-1-worker-3  State: RUNNABLE
Fork-ForkJoinPool-1-worker-5  State: RUNNABLE
Fork-ForkJoinPool-1-worker-5  State: RUNNABLE
Fork-ForkJoinPool-1-worker-6  State: RUNNABLE
Fork-ForkJoinPool-1-worker-6  State: RUNNABLE
Fork-ForkJoinPool-1-worker-7  State: RUNNABLE
Fork-ForkJoinPool-1-worker-7  State: RUNNABLE
Fork-ForkJoinPool-1-worker-8  State: RUNNABLE
Fork-ForkJoinPool-1-worker-8  State: RUNNABLE
Fork-ForkJoinPool-1-worker-9  State: RUNNABLE
Fork-ForkJoinPool-1-worker-9  State: RUNNABLE
Fork-ForkJoinPool-1-worker-10  State: RUNNABLE
Fork-ForkJoinPool-1-worker-10  State: RUNNABLE
Fork-ForkJoinPool-1-worker-11  State: RUNNABLE
Fork-ForkJoinPool-1-worker-11  State: RUNNABLE
Fork-ForkJoinPool-1-worker-12  State: RUNNABLE
Fork-ForkJoinPool-1-worker-12  State: RUNNABLE
Fork-ForkJoinPool-1-worker-13  State: RUNNABLE
.....
......
```

Comment: Add printout on every fork operation and info on thread that is being forked. You are probably doing more "forking" than "joining". (Just a guess, I never used forking in Java, only c++)

Comment: What you doing makes no sense whatsoever. Include enough code so we can compile it.

Comment: I did update the code,, Any help ?

Comment: Ok I'll look at the code more. But for now I see one questionable statement:  finder.fork()); returns ForkJoinTask<V>. Perhaps you should add(finder); and then do finder.fork() in another statement. You many not be joining on a finder but the return from a fork(). Will look at this more closely shortly.

Answer (score 0):

The major problem is that you fork() forever. There is no stopper code, such as:
if (computed < limiter) return;
Therefore, you add tasks to the deque, the thread picks up each task and forks more tasks, forever. I added a stopper to your code and ran it in Java7. The join() gets called but the outside iteration keeps going forever. So you have some logic problem there.

The second problem is that you misunderstand the F/J framework. This framework is not a general purpose parallel engine. It is academic code specifically designed to recursively walk down the leaves of a balanced tree (D.A.G.) Since you do not have a balanced tree you cannot process according to the examples given in the JavaDoc:
split left, right;
left.fork();
right.compute();
left.join();
And you are not doing recursive decomposition. Your code would be more appropriate for Java8's CountedCompler()